# How to delete rows based on column-realted criterion?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
COL_1    COL_2    COL_3    COL_4    NUM_1    NUM_2   NUM_3  NUM_4
NaN      AD       MD       TR       0        0       1      1
AD       TT       MD       TR       1        0       1      1
AD       TT       MD       NaN      0        0       1      0
```

I want to delete those rows that have `NUM_` equal to 1 for the column index right after `AD`. For example, the column index of `AD` in the first row is equal to 2 (`COL_2`). So, `NUM_3` (the next after `NUM_2`) is equal to 1. It means that this row should be deleted.

The result:

```
COL_1    COL_2    COL_3    COL_4    NUM_1    NUM_2   NUM_3  NUM_4
AD       TT       MD       TR       1        0       1      1
AD       TT       MD       NaN      0        0       1      0
```

Comment: Looks like @Psidom has given a nice hack for getting this working, but I think the larger issue is that this doesn't really look like an effective structure for storing your data. I'd give some thought to restructuring if you've got other similar manipulations you'll want to do.

Comment: Something like `cols = [{'AD': 2, 'MD': 3, 'TR': 4}, ...]` and `nums = [[0,0,1,1], ...]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the number of `COL*` columns is the same with `NUM*` columns, you can try the following vectorized method:

```
df[~((df.filter(like="COL") == "AD").values & 
     (df.filter(like="NUM") == 1).shift(-1, axis=1).fillna(False).values)
   .any(axis = 1)]
```

[image]

Comment: That's beautiful! Thank you for showcasing pandas so nicely!

Comment: Yes, the number of `COL*` columns is equal to `NUM*` columns. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, I get an error `TypeError: Could not compare ['AD'] with block values` when applying this code on my real dataset. Why does it happen?

Comment: The reason is that `NUM*` values in my real dataset contain `NaN` instead of 0 in some rows. If I substiitute them by 0 `df.filter(like='NUM_').replace({np.nan:0},inplace=True)`, it does not replace.

Comment: to replace missing values, you can use `.fillna(0)`.

Comment: When I just only run `df.filter(like="COL") == "AD"`, it produces this error `TypeError: Could not compare ['AD'] with block values`. So, finally I see that the problem is not with empty strings. I posted a new question here if you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283094/typeerror-could-not-compare-ad-with-block-values

Comment: Ok,resolved. This was happening because one of the columns contained only `NaN` values.